# PKM texture with ETC2 Compression giving black screen

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, texture-mapping

I am trying to upload a pkm texture in Android. I am able to read the image and get its width, height & data properly but the texture is showing black.

texture load function:

```
public static int loadCompressedTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId){
        final int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES30.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        Log.w(TAG, "ETC1 texture support: " + ETC1Util.isETC1Supported());
        if (textures[0] != 0)
        {
            // Read in the resource
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bodyf1pkm);
            ETC2Utils.ETC2Texture tex = null;
            try {
                tex = ETC2Utils.createTexture(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"tex width: "+tex.getWidth());
            Log.d(TAG,"tex height: "+tex.getHeight());

            // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
            GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

            // Set filtering
            GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES30.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES30.GL_REPEAT);
            GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES30.GL_REPEAT);
            // Load texture.
            GLES30.glCompressedTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,tex.getCompressionFormat(),tex.getWidth(),tex.getHeight(),0,tex.getDataSize(),tex.getData());


        }
        return textures[0];
    }
```

I am using a similar class of Rajawali's ETC2Util class (https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/blob/master/rajawali/src/main/java/org/rajawali3d/materials/textures/utils/ETC2Util.java) to load the data.
Data is getting loaded properly but texture is coming black. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it. It turns out that the compression format which I am using, (GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA8_ETC2_EAC) is 16 bit per pixel where as I was calculating the image size at 8 bit per pixel which is valid for GL_COMPRESSED_RGB8_ETC2